# Не компилируется после удаления #include "stdafx.h"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Почему первый вариант записи в Microsoft Visual Studio компилирует:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

а второй (более простой) нет:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello world!!!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку

> 1>c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(4)‌​: warning C4627: '#include ': skipped when looking for precompiled header use

В чем отличие и с чем это связано?

Comment: Не помешало бы прикладывать сообщения об ошибках, которые вы получаете при компиляции.

Comment: 1>c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(4): warning C4627: '#include <iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use

Comment: https://ravesli.com/urok-1-vvedenie-v-programmirovanie/ Привет туч хорошо объясняют главное запасись терпением и знаниям английского удачи!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрите.

Стандартная проблема языков, унаследовавших модульность C в виде `#include` — дикое время компиляции. Это связано с тем, что компилятор не может просто так скомпилировать header-файлы «про запас»: ведь то, что находится во включающем `.cpp`-файле до `#include`, может кардинально повлиять на смысл текста! (Представьте себе, например, `#define void int`.) Поэтому бедному компилятору приходится раз за разом перечитывать и перекомпилировать один и тот же заголовок, а также всё, что он в себя рекурсивно включает (а это могут быть десятки тысяч файлов!)

Для борьбы с этим одно из средств — предкомпилированные заголовки. Какая-то часть заголовочных файлов предкомпилируется, но чтобы корректно включить её, необходимо, чтобы она шла в самом начале .cpp-файла. Видите, почему? Потому что иначе в нём может встретиться директива, полностью меняющая смысл заголовочных файлов!

В Visual Studio предкомпилированные заголовки реализованы по умолчанию при помощи `stdafx.h`. Поэтому компилятор требует, чтобы `#include "stdafx.h"` всегда шло первой строкой. Вы, впрочем, можете легко обойти это поведение, покопавшись в настройках проекта: можно изменить имя предкомпилируемого заголовка или полностью отказаться от них. (Учтите, что в последнем случае ваш проект, возможно, будет компилироваться медленнее.)

---

Короче: добавьте `#include "stdafx.h"`, проблема, судя по всему, в нём. (Если бы вы привели сообщение об ошибке, было бы легче найти точную проблему.)

Comment: Я понял, спасибо, добавил `#include "stdafx.h"`, он, вроде как, показал сам текст "Hello World", и сразу закрыл выявив новую проблему: 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.  Что такое PDB file?

Comment: Это не проблема, то, что вы привели — не сообщение об ошибке. К каждому модулю может идти файл с отладочной информацией. Visual Studio не нашла отладочную информацию к рантайм-библиотеке и сообщила вам об этом. Это не мешает, вы ж не собираетесь отлаживать рантайм-библиотеку?

Comment: А окно закрылось сразу потому что программа закончила свою работу, разумеется :-) Если хотите, поставьте breakpoint на закрывающей фигурной скобке в `main`.

Comment: Простите, я плохо еще осведомлен в сленге программирования, поэтому не понял ваш вопрос с "отлаживанием рантайм-библиотек", но зато понял, почему оно сразу закрылось и что нужно сделать, чтобы не закрывалось :)

Comment: @ECF: окей. (1) насчёт PDB не парьтесь, это не ошибка, так и надо. (2) программа добежала до конца, вот окно и закрылось, (3) обязательно выясните, что такое breakpoint (оно же точка останова), как их ставить (это вам **очень** сильно пригодится!), и поставьте breakpoint на закрывающей скобке. Это решит вашу проблему.

Comment: @ECF: Ой, невнимательно прочитал ваш комментарий. Отлично, что разобрались!

Comment: @ECF: В файлах .PDB содержится отладочная информация. Например, как называются функции/классы, где они лежат, какие номера строк и файлы в исходниках и т. п. Они пригодятся для отладки модуля, который скомпилирован не вами, а кем-то другим.

Comment: А как добавление ещё одного заголовочного файла делает компиляцию быстрее? Остальные include'ы в коде ведь всё равно остались.

Comment: @Qwertiy: В этот файл помещаются часто используемые header'ы, и его содержимое предкомпилируется. Поскольку он подключается первым, с `#include "stdafx.h"` компилятор может начать компиляцию не с чистого листа, а с сохранённого состояния, соответствующего включению всех заголовков (рекурсивно), упомянутых в stdafx.h. Это по сути под миллион строк.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А остальные инклюды очень часто включают то, что уже есть в памяти после `#include "stdafx.h"`. Например, если ваш header инклюдит iostream.h, то реального чтения iostream.h не происходит, т. к. в памяти уже есть include guard после чтения stdafx.h (если там iostream.h был прямо или косвенно упомянут).

Comment: Т. е. вместо пары заголовочных файлов, которые мне нужны, и которые и так добавляются только один раз, подключается охапка того, что студии захочется?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вы можете положить  stdafx.h то, что вы хотите, а не студия.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы второй пример работал просто создавайте пустое консольное приложение в Visual Studio. Дело в том, что в студии есть различные шаблоны проектов и, если я не ошибаюсь, первый Ваш пример говорит о том, что вы создали Win32 проект, который, помимо всего прочего, включает и общий заголовок **stdafx**, необходимый для более быстрой компиляции(precompiled header) и сборки приложения в студии.

Comment: Спасибо. Я создал empty project, но, не сочтите за глупый вопрос, не могу никак найти в меню само окно, где бы я мог попробовать написать этот код. Если вы мне подскажите решение этой "нелегкой", думаю,  зачачи, то я бы мог заниматься по книжке, ведь там все коды именно в таком виде написаны :)

Comment: Создав новый проект, нужно добавить к нему файл. ПКМ по проекту, там будет пункт меню, позволяющий добавить файл.