# У меня ошибка, как исправить c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int menu()
{
    system("cls");
    int variant;
    cout << "Выберите вариант\n" << endl;
    cout << "1. Создать файл\n" << endl;
    cout << "2. Прочитать файл\n" << endl;
    cout << "0. Свалить\n" << endl;
    cout << ">>> ";
    cin >> variant;
    return variant;
}

void creafile()
{

    char buff[200];
    ofstream fout("text.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);
    fout << "arfgdsdujdsvbtyjunesh";// это текст вот.
    fout.close();
}

void readfile()
{


    ifstream f("text.txt", ios_base::in);
    string s;
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    cout << "Какой символ?";
    cin >> c;
    while (f){

        f >> s;
        i += (s[s.length()] == c) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    cout << "Таких строк: " << i;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    for (int variant = menu(); variant; variant = menu())


        switch (variant) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Приступим к созданию, для начала" << endl;
            creafile();
            break;
        case 2:
            readfile();
                break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

> error C2679: бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий правый
>   операнд типа "std::string" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Comment: А в какой строчке ошибка? Какой тип _левого_ операнда?

Comment: @VladD, мой внутренний вывод типов думает, что в `f >> s;`

Comment: @Nofate: `ifstream` вроде должен уметь, разве нет?

Comment: `f.getline(s);`

Comment: @VladD Может поток не создался?

Comment: @tutankhamun: Это была бы ошибка времени выполнения, а не компиляции.

Comment: @Abyx: для gcc не нужно: http://ideone.com/kH9o4v (но конечно не аргумент).

Comment: Но мы ещё не получили ответ на вопрос, что же собственно не компилируется.

Comment: @VladD Это да. Из комментариев получился слет телепатов

Comment: f >> s;  вот тут у меня подчеркивает

Comment: @Abyx спасибо!!!

Comment: Я взял исходник как он есть, только stdafx выкинул, и спокойненько скомпилил его  mingw32. Никаких ошибок, все запускается и работает.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, надо писать все необходимые файлы

```
#include <string>
```

Во-вторых, надо было создавать пустой проект (т. е. с соответствующей галочкой и без галочки про безопасный жизненный цикл).

И в-третьих, надо указывать номер строки с ошибкой (а лучше саму строку).

Comment: спасибо, буду знать

Comment: Ну, SDL придумано не просто так. И не использовать stdafx означает увеличение времени компиляции.

Comment: я его стал отключать после того как SDL ругалось на fopen

Comment: @VladD, какую пользу ты видишь от SDL? И что не так с компиляцией без stdafx?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Про stdafx [вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416186/10105).

Comment: @Qwertiy: SDL ловит (некоторые) баги наподобие срыва стека в рантайме. Соответственно, код получается более безопасный. С ним у тебя меньше риск, что открыв твоей программой документ из интернета, юзер случайно запустит wishmaster. Можно, конечно, доверять себе, но я обычно не доверяю настолько, чтобы пренебрегать предоставленными мне инструментами для повышения безопасности кода.