# Стандарнтые заголовочные файлы внутри stdafx.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, header

Стоит ли включать в предкомпилированный заголовочный файл `stdafx.h` заголовочные файлы стандартной библиотеки (`string`, `algorithm` и т.п.), ведь они не изменяются?

Смущает то, что необходимо писать `#include "stdafx.h"` в каждом `.cpp` файле. Используется Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Почему - необходимо? Никто не заставляет, по большому счету... Да, вам дают такую заготовку, но если вы напишете без нее, в принципе ничего страшного не произойдет...

Comment: @Harry ну не знаю, если не пишешь первой строкой `#include "stdafx.h` во всех `.cpp` файлах, то в `VS15` у меня выпадает ошибка, где в скобках специально написано что-то типа "возможно, вы забыли написать ..."

Comment: Вам как доказать? Скриншоты если выложу куда-нибудь - вам этого хватит? :)

Comment: @Harry http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416098/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-include-stdafx-h

Comment: @Harry тут, например, явно сказано про это
https://habrahabr.ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/227521/

Comment: http://i85.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1112/53/42da2a0bca7b60d15949ceaf58479b53.jpg   http://i85.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1112/dc/2421f61ef5f713f24867ae1dd92ebadc.jpg   http://i85.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1112/d4/622022b609bf36d09308d46f6dcdcfd4.jpg

Comment: И что там написано? Что это надо делать **обязательно**? Там написано, что это **можно** делать... Впрочем, что касается лично меня, то я старомоден и предпочитаю в основном работать по старинке, из командной строки... :(

Comment: @Harry вы, скорее всего, просто не используете этот механизм и `.pch` - файл не генерируется

Comment: @Harry ясно, вы не так меня поняли, а точнее невнимательно прочитали вопрос. Там не написано, что использовать precompiled headers необходимо)

Comment: А я вам о чем пишу? О том и говорю, что это вполне можно не делать :) Кстати, использовать предкомпилированные заголовки опять же можно и без stdafx.h

Comment: Ну, я вас понял именно так. Значит, вопрос исчерпан :)

Comment: @Harry вопрос состоял в том, стоит ли добавлять туда стандартные библиотеки

Answer (score 4):

Если вы приняли решение использовать Precompiled Headers (для ускорения сборки), то заголовки стандартных библиотек *нужно* включать в `stdafx.h` ведь для этого весь сыр-бор и затевается, чтобы их один раз компилятор распарсил, и далее для всех остальных файлов уже использовал приготовленные (прекомпилинные) файлы. Соответственно как раз *не изменяемые* файлы и надо включать в него, чтобы не вызывать лишний раз пересборки этих precompiled headers.

Механизм прекомпиленных заголовков довольно гибкий. Вы можете отключить его полностью, или для отдельных файлов. А также для одной группы файлов использовать один precompiled header, для другой группы другой. Ну и имя `stdafx.h` хоть и по дефолту, но не фиксированное, можете изменить на любое другое.

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то я не советую включать заголовочные файлы внутрь заголовка  `<stdafx.h>`.

Во-первых, это делает код менее читабельным, так как сеет сомнение у читающего ваш код, включили ли вы правильно все заголовки, или программа компилируется лишь из-за того, что в некоторой реализации стандартной библиотеки в стандартный заголовок был включен другой стандартный заголовок.

Во-вторых, такой код не будет переносим на платформы, где отсутствует заголовок `<stdafx.h>`. Если же не включать в него заголовочные файлы, то вам будет достаточно просто его закомментировать или удалить.  То есть упрощается работа. И никто не будет спрашивать, а что это за заголовок.

Comment: На каких платформах может отсутствовать заголовок "stdafx.h" ? В том смысле, что это пользовательский файл, а не стандартный, т.е. идет наравне с остальными вашими файлами с кодом.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Возникают вопросы, что он означает. А самое главное, совершенно не видно, какие стандартные заголовки используются. Более того разные единицы трансляции могут использовать разные заголовки, а захламление их ненужными заголовками приводит к увеличению времени компиляции на тех платформах, где смысл заголовка Microsoft не известен.

Comment: Согласен, что не видно пока не откроешь сам stdafx.h. С другой стороны gcc также может работать с precompiled headers (хотя вроде не так эффективно как студийный). Т.е. это не то, чтобы эксклюзив от майкрософта.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Эксклюзив от Microsoft - это этот заголовок.

Comment: Не понял на счет эксклюзива. Вы с таким же успехом можете использовать механизм прекомпиленных заголовков и в других компиляторах (intel, gcc, borland). И даже использовать то же самое имя (`stdafx.h`), вряд ли оно запатентовано.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Microsoft выбрал именно это имя. Оно ничего не говорит для других компиляторов.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Извините, но я не участвую в чатах.

Comment: Ничего страшного, я могу ответить здесь: Оно для микрософтового компилятора тоже ничего не говорит, пока явно в командной строке он его не получит.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Оно по умолчанию включается во все проекты, если писать код через IDE. Поэтому большинство кода, написанного с помощью MS VC++, содержит этот заголовок, и читающие код понимают его значение. Это уже де-факто стандартное средство Microsoft

Comment: Вы предлагаете не включать в `stdafx.h` заголовочные файлы. И комментировать его включение на других платформах. Для чего тогда вообще его держать в проекте?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Нсли проект был создан в MS VS, как не пустой проект, то он уже содержит эту директиву. Для компиляции под MS VC++ это удобно и не требует временных затрат по настройке проекта.

Comment: Если проект был создан в Wizard-е студии, и в вопросах от Wizard-а не была снята галка "precompiled headers", то да, будет задействован "stdafx.h". Что не мешает в последствии отключить их использование в пару кликов. Что будет гораздо быстрее, нежели в последствии комментировать/использовать директивы условной компиляции на других платформах.